# How to authenticate a java web app with KeyRock?

Tags: fiware

We are trying to create a user authentication in our web app ( that we are developing in Java Spring MVC). For our authentication we want to use the token and user info acquired from the users fiware.lab account on global instance of keyrock.

**Since Keyrock is based on OAuth2 protocol, what is the best approach to use keyrock from our web app?**

**Is there a java library that we could use for this purpose?**

**Is there a way to integrate spring security or apache oltu?**

**Every example would be more than welecome.**

We only have the implementation of node.js but we need a java version of [this](https://github.com/ging/oauth2-example-client):

```
var express = require('express');
var OAuth2 = require('./oauth2').OAuth2;
var config = require('./config');


// Express configuration
var app = express();
app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    secret: "skjghskdjfhbqigohqdiouk"
}));

app.configure(function () {
    "use strict";
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
    //app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});


// Config data from config.js file
var client_id = config.client_id;
var client_secret = config.client_secret;
var idmURL = config.idmURL;
var response_type = config.response_type;
var callbackURL = config.callbackURL;

// Creates oauth library object with the config data
var oa = new OAuth2(client_id,
                    client_secret,
                    idmURL,
                    '/oauth2/authorize',
                    '/oauth2/token',
                    callbackURL);

// Handles requests to the main page
app.get('/', function(req, res){

    // If auth_token is not stored in a session cookie it sends a button to redirect to IDM authentication portal 
    if(!req.session.access_token) {
        res.send("Oauth2 IDM Demo.<br><br><button onclick='window.location.href=\"/auth\"'>Log in with FI-WARE Account</button>");

    // If auth_token is stored in a session cookie it sends a button to get user info
    } else {
        res.send("Successfully authenticated. <br><br> Your oauth access_token: " +req.session.access_token + "<br><br><button onclick='window.location.href=\"/user_info\"'>Get my user info</button>");
    }
});

// Handles requests from IDM with the access code
app.get('/login', function(req, res){

    // Using the access code goes again to the IDM to obtain the access_token
    oa.getOAuthAccessToken(req.query.code, function (e, results){

        // Stores the access_token in a session cookie
        req.session.access_token = results.access_token;

        res.redirect('/');

    });
});

// Redirection to IDM authentication portal
app.get('/auth', function(req, res){
    var path = oa.getAuthorizeUrl(response_type);
    res.redirect(path);
});

// Ask IDM for user info
app.get('/user_info', function(req, res){
    var url = config.idmURL + '/user/';

    // Using the access token asks the IDM for the user info
    oa.get(url, req.session.access_token, function (e, response) {

        var user = JSON.parse(response);
        res.send("Welcome " + user.displayName + "<br> Your email address is " + user.email + "<br><br><button onclick='window.location.href=\"/logout\"'>Log out</button>");
    });
});

// Handles logout requests to remove access_token from the session cookie
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){

    req.session.access_token = undefined;
    res.redirect('/');
});

console.log('Server listen in port 80. Connect to localhost');
app.listen(80);
```

**Edit 1**
Here is my set up:

[image]

[image]

and the end result error I get when I call the token:

[image]

Comment: PS, you question is not fully understandable, as it's a mix of languages. Please, update the post so anyone can give you a better feedback :)

Comment: sry, I was translating the question

Answer (score 2):

[Fiware devguide](https://www.fiware.org/devguides/handling-authorization-and-access-control-to-apis/how-to-implement-oauth2-in-your-applications/) explains how this oauth2 flow works against KeyRock. 
There also, you can find linked [several oauth2 implementations](http://oauth.net/2/) like [scribe-data](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java), where you can find several examples on how to use oauth2 authentication against some of the most extended social networks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, we were just looking for a complete solution like the one for node.js

Comment: Well, as it's true that it doesn't work "out of the box" like in the examples provided, the documentation is prettly simple and easy, https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/getting-started and of course is a complete solution, you just need to integrate it yourself in your application (as you would have to do with the `node.js` one).

Comment: I haven't been in contact with java since a long time ago, so I guess at this point I cannot be useful anymore. Just few things to point. Why are you extending from 'googleAPI' and not from 'FiwareLAB' (the other file you wrote)? The code you have will never work as you are doing requests against google and not Fiware... Please make sure you configure it properly